# выборка записей из таблицы и группировка по полю

Tags: mysql, sql

Приветствую. Есть таблица комментариев, в которой нас интересуют поля `uid`, `user_id`. Так вот, нужно выбрать из этой таблицы все уникальные `user_id`, количество записей, в которых он встречается и `Uid` этих записей

```
SELECT COUNT(*), user_id, uid FROM `comments` WHERE user_id> 0 GROUP BY user_id
```

запрос такого вида возвращает уникальные `user_id`, количество записей с ними и только последний `uid` из всех. Как изменить запрос, чтобы возвращались все `Uid`? допускается их склеить в строку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

если можно склеивать в строку, тогда попробуйте вариант такой

```
SELECT COUNT(*), user_id, GROUP_CONCAT(uid SEPARATOR ', ')
FROM `comments` 
WHERE user_id> 0 
GROUP BY user_id
```